# htaccess - adding a directory to the querystring with original querystring

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've had a good read through all the other htaccess questions on here, but you know when you've read too much and get confused? Well, I'm at that stage!

I'm trying to redirect requests from `/app/test/ddd/?var=something` to index.php which is in the root and deals with the querystrings.

I've managed to get this partly working in that no matter which directory under `/app/test/` is called, it redirects it to index.php with the current querystring; but I'd like to add the `ddd` as `var2=` in the querystring.

The other problem comes when I try to use index.php to post to another file called formsubmit.php - it just goes back to index.php again.

Here's what I have and is kinda working on the directory side:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/
RewriteRule ^formsubmit.php - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?var2=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

I'll be grateful for any help!

Comment: I can't test but you want something like: `RewriteRule /app/test/(.*)/ /index.php?var2=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Tried this:
`RewriteRule ^app/test/(.*)/$ /index.php?var2=$1 [L,QSA]`
Which on the form submit front now gives me a 404, but doesn't give me a var2 in the querystring

Comment: where is your htaccess file?

Comment: in the root directory

Comment: None of your rules do redirect?

Comment: What abracadaver said is mostly true (you corrected the rule correctly). As for the 404 part, check with help from the developer console where you send your data. Do you send it to `/app/test/formsubmit.php` or `/formsubmit.php`? Does that file actually exist? As for `var2` not being appended: I guess `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` does not pass. You could attempt to add `AcceptPathInfo Off` to the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help guys. So, after a bit more sleep, I came up with this which works just fine!

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/app/test/(.*)/$`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index\.php?var2=%1 [R=301,L,QSA]`

Just in case someone else is looking through for a similar answer... This takes the name of the directory called in the RewriteCond where (.*) appears and stores it as a variable.
The rewrite rule then uses this variable (%1) to add the name of the directory called to the querystring, along with including the original query string (QSA)